# Prepopulating Fields on visualforce page if checkbox is checked

Tags: visualforce

I have a visualforce page with 2 main sections: "System Administrator" and "Billing Contact" what i want is if the "Same as System Admin" checkbox is checked then the Billing Contact fields get prepopulated with the System Administrator fields.

here's my vf code:

```
function prepopSA(){
    if(document.getElementById("{!$Component.pg.frm.pbbc1.pbsbc1.chkbc}").checked==true){
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.pg.frm.pbbc2.pbspc2.BC_FN}').value=
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.pg.frm.pbsa1.pbsa2.pbssa2.SA_FN}').value;

}
}


</script>


<apex:form id="frm">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Key Contacts Information" id="pb1">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Company" columns="1" Collapsible="true" id="pb2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Portal_Key_User_Input__c.Portal_Company__c}" required="true" label="My Company"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlock id="pbsa1">


        <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbssa1" title="System Administrator (This contact is responsible for creating, amending and deleting system users for your organization)" columns="4" Collapsible="true">
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

          <apex:pageBlock id="pbsa2"> 
          <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4" id="pbssa2"> 
            <apex:inputField value="{!Portal_Key_User_Input__c.First_Name1__c}" label="First Name" required="true" id="SA_FN"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Portal_Key_User_Input__c.Last_Name1__c}" label="Last Name" required="true" id="SA_LN"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Portal_Key_User_Input__c.Email1__c}" label="Email" required="true" Id="SA_E"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Portal_Key_User_Input__c.Phone1__c}" label="Phone" required="true" Id="SA_P"/>


            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:pageBlock>

            <apex:pageBlock id="pbbc1">
           <!-- <apex:pageBlock >-->
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbsbc1" title="Billing Contact" columns="4" Collapsible="true">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Portal_Key_User_Input__c.Same_as_System_Admin__c}" id="chkbc" onchange="prepopSA();"/>
            <!--<apex:actionSupport event="onclick" rerender="pbbc2" action="{!sa_bc}" id="asbc"/>
            </apex:inputCheckbox>-->
            <apex:commandButton value="Same as System Admin" action="{!sa_bc}"/> 


            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <!--</apex:pageBlock>-->

            <apex:pageBlock id="pbbc2" rendered="{!sabc}">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4" id="pbsbc2">

            <apex:inputField value="{!Portal_Key_User_Input__c.First_Name2__c}" label="First Name" id="BC_FN"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Portal_Key_User_Input__c.Last_Name2__c}" label="Last Name" ID="BC_LN"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Portal_Key_User_Input__c.email2__c}" label="Email" ID="BC_E"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Portal_Key_User_Input__c.Phone2__c}" label="Phone" ID="BC_P"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

please help! thank you1

Comment: what problem are you faicing, could you highlight the problem and point out where in your code you are stuck? If you are new to the platform, [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules)  might be better suited for you.

Comment: so in prepopSA() im checking if "chkbc" is checked and if it is the prepopulate First Name in Billing Contact - "BC_FN" with First Name in System Administrator "SA_FN"